# CodeLite not starting on fedora 32

Tags: fedora, codelite

I installed CodeLite using the rpm package from their website.
When I tried to open the program for the first time nothing happened.
Trying to start codelite from the console i get the following error message:

```
codelite: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have installed SDL and SDL to try to solve this problem, but it didn't make a difference. the not found file seems to be at the right place. Im relatively new to Linux so I might forgeting something?

```
[leon@linux ~]$ ls /usr/lib/libSDL*
/usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0  /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
```

RPM: codelite-14.0-2.fc32.x86_64
Fedora 32

I really don't know how to continue from here so every help would be appreciated

Comment: Any improvement after `sudo ldconfig`?

Comment: i tried that multiple times, still no difference, thank you anyways!

Comment: If you run `ldd` on the `codelite` executable, does it show all the libraries it can't find?